# How do I include src files from a library I have written into cmake of android project

Tags: cmake

Essentially I have written a library in c++ which i would like to use in my android application and I have yet to find a way to include files from folders in the parent directory.

**Projects Directory**

```
 my_c++_project
                src/
                    cpp and header files
 Android Application/
                App/
                    CMakeList
                    src/
```

Comment: If you're building libraries, have you used `target_link_library`?  You can embed include paths directly in a library.

Comment: @StephenNewell isn't target_link_library for prebuilt libraries ?

Comment: @StephenNewell i tried to add the cpps of the c++ project in the add_library command with explicits paths but android studio seems to ignore them and does  not build it. Rather justs builds the java portion of the code and crash reporting that the native library could not be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a quick solution, then you will want to use `target_include_directories` that can be used like this:

```
target_include_directories(androi_app PUBLIC ${MY_CPP_PROJ_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

You then generate your android application using something like this

```
cmake ../ -DMY_CPP_PROJ_INCLUDE_DIR=/your/cpp/proj/src/folder
```

However, I would suggest to instead use `CMake` to generate the necessary build files for your `my_c++_project`. Once you have the proper setup, you can simply use `target_link_libraries(my_android_app my_cpp_proj)` (assuming your c++ project is called `my_cpp_proj`).

[Here's a fairly minimal example](https://github.com/samaursa/cmake_test_lib) of a `CMake` project which you can use for your `my_c++_project`.